# Recursive Polar Coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, euclidean-geometry, polar-coordinates

Given a list of Cartesian coordinates $p_0, p_1, ..., p_n$, where $p_i = (x_i, y_i, z_i) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, how might one express the polar coordinates of each point recursively in the local frame of the previous point?

I can calculate the base case polar coordinates for $p_0$ in the world frame like so:
$$r_0 = \sqrt{x_0^2 + y_0^2 + z_0^2 }$$
$$\theta_0 = \arctan (y_0, x_0)$$
$$\phi_0 = \arccos (z_0 \ r_0)$$

I am unsure how this would extend into local frames of each sequential point and with arbitrary point orientations.

Visually, I would like to derive a general formula to find the red text in my diagram.

[Diagram of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCufM.png)

Comment: Points do not have orientations. Frames of reference do. You have multiple frames of reference, each of which has a point as its origin, but the frame is more than just the origin.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for the insight, I will adjust my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspected your figure but it seems that the local coordinate systems (CS) seem arbitrary.

First, you can get the basis vectors $i_n,j_n,k_n$ of each local frame $X_nY_nZ_n$ represented in the world CS (the specific CS is not important though) by coordinate transformation (using Euler angles).

[image]

Then, we define
$$
r: = OR = p_n - p_{n-1}\\
q: = OQ = OR + RQ = r - (r\cdot k_{n-1})k_{n-1}
$$
where $r$ is the relative position vector of $P_i$ with respect to $P_{i-1}$, and $q$ is the projection of $r$ onto $XY$ plane of the local CS.
The indices are omitted from now on. Let us define a unit vector
$$
l = \frac{r \times k}{|r \times k|}
$$
Then, we have
$$
|q||r|\sin\theta_i = (q \times r ) \cdot l
$$
and
$$
(i \times q) \cdot k = |q|\sin\phi_i\\
i \cdot q = |q|\cos\phi_i
$$
Therefore,
$$
\theta_i = \arcsin\frac{(q \times r ) \cdot l}{|q||r|}\\
\phi_i = \mathrm{atan2}\left( (i \times q) \cdot k, i \cdot q\right)
$$
In most cases, $\mathrm{atan2}$ is preferred to $\arctan$ due to its broader range $(-\pi, \pi]$.

The key is to find $i,j,k$ and $q,r,l$ for each local CS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you point me to where I could learn about coordinate transformation (using Euler angles)?

Comment: @Dimen3ional https://catalogimages.wiley.com/images/db/pdf/0471371459.excerpt.pdf

Comment: @Dimen3ional I referred to Euler angles because you mentioned them before you edit the post, but as you know the parametrization is not unique. A coordinate transformation is usually represented by a rotation matrix.

Comment: @Dimen3ional See p. 26 of the reference, but you'll have to follow from the beginning to fully understand how it works. It's a very good reference!

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated.